# Identity server3 : User Info endpoint returns null Claims

Tags: identityserver3

I am using Authorization Code flow and I am trying to get the user information using user info endpoint, but I am not getting claims. I've enabled IncludeInIdToken for some claims like name profile email and when decode Idtoken I was not able to see the above claims. 
I've tried by debugging the method GetProfileDataAsync, here I found the "Name" property coming null, since I am using the AD group I need this Name property here.
I tried to save "Name" into global variable in LocalLoginAsync method and used the same in GetProfileDataAsync method. Now I have added claims to the TaskResult, but I am getting count '0' in the response

When I request for tokens by using code I am able to see the following result in Claims

[image: Claims]

and I am not able to see those claims in IdToken,
[image: Id_token]

Next, time when request using user info endpoint by using access token I am not getting any Claim except "sub" or no Name property.

How can I get Claim with User Info endpoint response

Answer (score 0):

I've tried by debugging the code and found the issue, since I am doing the mistake like

return Task.FormResult(identity.Claims.where(x=>context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Types)));

instead of doing

context.IssuedClaims = identity.Claims.where(x=>context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Types));
return Task.FromResult(0);

But still I am getting the username(Name) property null with user info endpoint..,

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are requesting the `profile` scope in your request. If this is true then `username` is not a valid scope and does not form part of the [list of standard claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#StandardClaims) for this scope. you should rename your claim to either `nickname` or `preferred_username`